# Windows Phone Contacts and Date Modified

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contacts

Is there any way I can know the last modification date of a contact or when it was added ? Because in my application I need for example to synchronize and get all newly added contacts and something like that.
Also isn't there any unique identifier for the contact or at least the account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique identifier and no properties for modified date or creation date.

I suspect the intention was to try and protect user privacy by discouraging the building of apps which would track contact information.

The best that can probably be done is to use a combination of fields that are unlikely to change very frequently (i.e. name & DOB) and use these as the identifying factor. You could then store a hash of all information against the ID and if the hash doesn't match when checked in the future you'll know that something has changed.